# Fetch Data Only Once - Remix

Tags: remix.run

I'm using Remix(1.16) and trying to fetch data from the database only once.

I have data that I fetch from the database that will never change. These data are usually options of select input fields.

*What I tried:*

Fetching it on the loader() of my root and passing  this data to the rest of the project by the useOutletContext(). The problem is that on every **post request** that happens on the app the loader on the root is also refreshed and fetch the data again.

**Getting the data on root**

```
export async function loader({ request }) {
  const staticData = await getStaticData(request)
  return staticData
}
```

**Passing the data on context on root**

```
  ...
  const staticData = useLoaderData()
  return (
    <Document>
      <Outlet context={{ staticData}} />
    </Document>
  );
```

If someone could help me with that I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the export `shouldRevalidate` to your route. If you return `false`, then Remix will not call your loader again.

https://remix.run/docs/en/main/route/should-revalidate